# Altering views in grid view

Tags: android, gridview, view

I have views in gridview in activity A. In activity B if some actions occur, I want to add little check mark on the view in gridview. And when I come back to activity A, I want to show this view with this little check mark on it in the same grid view. How I am going to do that?

Here is my activity that contains grid view

```
public class LogoSelectionActivity extends Activity {


static int pos;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_logos);



    GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));


    gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            pos = position;

            if(ImageAdapter.items[position] == 0){
                Intent intent = new Intent(LogoSelectionActivity.this, LogoActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra ("clicked_position", position);
                startActivity(intent);
            }else{

                Intent intent = new Intent(LogoSelectionActivity.this, CorrectActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

And here is my other activity where I compare inputs:

```
public class LogoActivity extends Activity{

EditText text;
Button check;
Boolean a;
int id;
Names name;
@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_logo);

    check = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Check_button);
    text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    ImageView view = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    final ImageView incorrect = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.incorrect);
    switch (getIntent().getIntExtra ("clicked_position", -1))
    {
      case 0:
        view.setImageResource(R.drawable.adese);
        id = R.drawable.adese;
        break;
      case 1:
         view.setImageResource(R.drawable.birvar);
         id = R.drawable.birvar;
         break;
      case 2:
         view.setImageResource(R.drawable.agaoglu);
         break;
      case 3:
          view.setImageResource(R.drawable.akinsoft);
          break;
      default:
         view.setImageResource(R.drawable.afra);
         id = R.drawable.afra;
    }
    name = Names.forDrawable(id);
    check.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            a=name.isCorrect(text.getText().toString());
            if(a==true){    
            ImageAdapter.items[LogoSelectionActivity.pos] = 1;
            Intent intent = new Intent(LogoActivity.this, CorrectActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            }
            else{
                incorrect.setVisibility(0);
            }
        }
        });
    }
}
```

If a returns true, I want to put a little check mark on view in grid view when user get backs to first activity.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
package com.shreeexample.grid;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    private Context context;
    int checked=0;
    private final String[] mobileValues;
    public ImageAdapter(Context context, String[] mobileValues) {
        this.context = context;
        this.mobileValues = mobileValues;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return mobileValues.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final ImageView img_select;
        final int selectedPosition = -1; 

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View gridView;

        if (convertView == null) {

            gridView = new View(context);

            // get layout from mobile.xml
            gridView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.two, null);

            // set value into textview
            TextView textView = (TextView) gridView
                    .findViewById(R.id.grid_item_label);
            textView.setText(mobileValues[position]);

            // set image based on selected text
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) gridView
                    .findViewById(R.id.grid_item_image);
            img_select = (ImageView)gridView.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_image_select);

            String mobile = mobileValues[position];

            if (mobile.equals("Windows")) {
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            } else if (mobile.equals("iOS")) {
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            } else if (mobile.equals("Blackberry")) {
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            } else {
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            }

            imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    img_select.setFocusable(true);
                    img_select.setEnabled(true);
                    if(checked==0)
                    {

                        img_select.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.btn_plus);


                    checked =1;
                }
                else
                {
                    img_select.setBackgroundResource(0);
                    checked=0;
                }


                }
            });

        } else {
            gridView = (View) convertView;
        }

        return gridView;
    }
}
```

for this make a layout like this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/grid_item_image"
        android:layout_width="50px"
        android:layout_height="50px"
        android:layout_marginRight="10px"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" >
    </ImageView>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/grid_item_image_select"
        android:layout_width="50px"
        android:layout_height="50px"
        android:layout_marginRight="10px"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" >
    </ImageView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/grid_item_label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="label"
        android:layout_marginTop="5px"
        android:textSize="15px" 
        android:layout_below="@+id/grid_item_image">
    </TextView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

A GridView uses data from an adapter. You'd have to change the data of the adapter and notify the adapter that the data has been changed. The method for the update can then take care of the canges in the Gridview. Maybe this example could help you onwards:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html

And to have activity A react  to actions in activity B, I think you may want to have a look at Intents and Intent Filters:
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html

Otherwise, please provide some of your code for us to comment on.